Program launches fine when exec'd manually but silently fails via systemd service
I have a C++ app that I can run manually but fails when being run by a systemd service with no error message. Why is this happening?
I can run the program myself just fine:
$ DISPLAY=:0 /home/pi/myApp/myApp &

But when I have this executed via systemd service it doesn't launch. The chain of execution is:
kiosk.service -> kiosk.sh -> myApp
Here is my systemd service (kiosk.service):
[Unit]
Description=Run app in kiosk mode
Wants=graphical.target
After=graphical.target

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 20
Environment=DISPLAY=:0.0
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/pi/kiosk.sh
Restart=on-abort
User=pi
Group=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target

Here's kiosk.sh that runs my app:
#!/bin/bash

# This script has been adapted from: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-kiosk/

# Disable screensaver / blank screen due to inactivity
xset s noblank
xset s off
xset -dpms

# Hide mouse cursor using the unclutter program
DISPLAY=:0 unclutter -idle 0.5 -root &

# Launch of app with our params
DISPLAY=:0 /home/pi/myApp/myApp &


$ systemctl status kiosk.service says:
○ kiosk.service - Launch app in kiosk mode
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kiosk.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2023-12-27 19:10:13 EST; 5min ago
   Duration: 48ms
   Main PID: 1483 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 54ms

Dec 27 19:09:53 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting kiosk.service - Launch app in kiosk mode...
Dec 27 19:10:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started kiosk.service - Launch app in kiosk mode.
Dec 27 19:10:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: kiosk.service: Deactivated successfully.

If I do $ sh /home/pi/kiosk.sh it also runs fine, so it seems nothing is wrong with my shell launcher script.
I'm thinking there's some environment variable context that changes when a program is executed from a systemd service? Any ideas?

Don't run MyApp in the background when running this as a service.

And take out the DISPLAY=:0 assignments in the script, it should get those from the environment.

Thank you! That got systemctl status kiosk.service to reveal an error by myApp: error while loading shared libraries: libglfw.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory -- myApp is supposed to load shared objects from a /libs dir locally to the executable. Is there a way to launch myApp with local context?

Are you setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH in your interactive environment? You'll need to add that environment variable to the service configuration.

Added export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/pi/myApp/libs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /etc/profile and it didn't seem to change anything. Looking into this further

/etc/profile isn't run by systemd services.

See https://serverfault.com/questions/413397/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-systemd-service for how to set environment variables for systemd.

Thanks, it appears to be working now! Added Environment="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/pi/myApp/libs:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/lib" under the [Service] section of my kiosk.service. Feel free to answer and I'll mark as solution if you want, otherwise I'll do it in a bit

There's no need to run the application in the background. All systemd services are running as daemons. So remove the & after MyApp.
Your application apparently depends on libraries that aren't in the standard place, you need to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable. So add
Environment="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/pi/myApp/libs:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/lib"

to the [Service] section.
